# UrlBuilder query string encoding not working

Tags: java, url, spring-webclient

WebClient urlbuilder query string has changed

```java
String key = "bEyBOCB4SoL%2F1gI%s"

webClient.get()
.scheme("http")
.host("www.localhost:8080")
.queryParam("key", URLEncoder.encode(key, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()))
.build()

... send request
```

query string has changed "**bEyBOCB4SoL%25252F1gI%2525**"

origin = "**bEyBOCB4SoL%2F1gI%s**"

Answer (score 2):

You are triple-encoding the value.

- The `key` string is already encoded, see the `%2F` which is the encoded value of `/`.
- You then manually encode by calling `URLEncoder.encode(...)`, which will encode `%` as `%25`.
- The `queryParam(...)` method will then encode again, which will encode `%` as `%25`.

The result is the `%25252F` you see.

Change the code:

```java
String key = "bEyBOCB4SoL/1gI%s";
```

```java
.queryParam("key", key)
```

The result will be: `bEyBOCB4SoL%2F1gI%25s`

Comment: i mean when enclude '%' in String. url has added '25' behind '%' how can i resolve?

Comment: i replaced '%' to '%25' but nothing changed

Comment: @javaOne Of course encoding changes `%` to `%25`. What did you think URL-encoding does, if not that?

Comment: API required '%' but i send '%25' how can i do??